# Using ng-animate with animate.css in angular 1.2 rc2

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, animate.css

I working on moving some existing angular code from **1.1.5** to **1.2.0-rc.2**. Some of the major differences is the use of `ngAnimate`.

I'm using a combination of `ng-if` with `animate.css` in `ng-class`.

### See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bg1Epo?p=preview) for a working example.

The issue I'm having is that while the `fadeIn` animation works fine, the element that is supposed to disappear takes close to a second to vanish - there's no smooth transition between the two. This is a simplified example of what I'm actually doing, and I prefer to use `ng-if` (I realize this example can be simplified with `ng-repeat`).

Is this an issue with `ng-if`, or something that has to do with the implementation, `animate.css` or something else? thanks.

Comment: This article may help: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your 'hidding' class from `ng-hide` to `fadeOut`.  `fadeOut`, like `fadeIn` is the animate.css way of doing it.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/l0xqnE?p=preview

```
<div ng-if="showFirst" ng-class="{ 'animated fadeIn' : showFirst, 'fadeOut': !showFirst }">
```

Comment: There is still an issue with cross fade and your example doesn't work too well for me on Firefox (Linux and OSX), but I guess this stuff comes with the "RC" label. Thanks!

Comment: The animations are from CSS, Angular only add/removes classes to trigger the animations.  Because browser doesn't support them all the same, there are some differences between the browsers. If you wanted them all to be the same, you should consider JS animations via Angular.